# Avoid gulp task to finish automatically

Tags: node.js, gulp

I need that my gulp task stop to finish automatically. I have some file watchers that works after gulp finish, but it prints something like that:

```
[10:26:38] Using gulpfile ~\gulpfile.js
[10:26:38] Starting "watch"...
[10:26:38] Finished "watch" after 1.34 ms

[10:26:38] File modified abc.css.
[10:26:38] File modified def.js.
```

Basically I do:

```
gulp.task("watch", function () {
    // using require("gulp-watch")
    startWatchers();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple solution, but I don't know if is the best. I just returned a instance of node `Stream`. Basically:

```
gulp.task("watch", function () {
    // using require("gulp-watch")
    startWatchers();

    // using require("stream");
    return new Stream();
});
```